# Is there any support for mouse wheel and Apple track-pad in Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0, mousewheel, trackpad

One of my Silverlight applications has some users to use it on Apple Macs. They complain that the mouse wheel and track-pad don't work.

From the research I've done, it seems that this isn't supported in browser-hosted applications on Macs.

Does Silverlight 5 add improved support? Is it on Microsoft's radar for a future version of Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While my initial thought was that it works in 4 and 5, I elected to test it again under the silverlight 5 beta.

Mousewheel scrolling does not seem to work for scrollviewers or similar.  I can't test the trackpad, as I don't have a mac laptop.

Comment: Thanks - I assume you mean you've tested it on a Mac but don't have a laptop (which presumeably is where the track pad exists).

Answer (score 1):

In fact I noticed the exact same issue during a recent demo to some partners. Using the trackpad, they were unabled to perform deepzoom zooming.

I am however quite sure it worked before. Therefore, it looks like a Mac Os (or Safari) update broke this Feature. It's a good thing: Mouse wheel and trackpad support on MacOs are on Silverlight features list, MS will normally correct the issue, maybe for the next release (I suggest to cross our fingers)